# Python float - str - float weirdness

Tags: python, string, floating-point, floating-accuracy, ieee-754

```
>>> float(str(0.65000000000000002))

0.65000000000000002

>>> float(str(0.47000000000000003))

0.46999999999999997     ???
```

What is going on here?
How do I convert `0.47000000000000003` to string and the resultant value back to float?

I am using Python 2.5.4 on Windows.

Comment: RC: I think many many people (yes, programmers too) don't eevn know that IEEE 754 defines floating-point numbers (not everyone reads language specifications :-)). So I'd actually think that the "floating-point" tag would be a better choice unless there are specific questions about the standard itself.

Comment: surely those that ask these kind of questions don't know what ieee-754 is...

Comment: wasn't aware of the floating point tag but sure it's better than the name of the spec.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`str(0.47000000000000003)` give `'0.47'` and `float('0.47')` can be `0.46999999999999997`. 
This is due to the way floating point number are represented (see this [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754) article)

Note: `float(repr(0.47000000000000003))` or `eval(repr(0.47000000000000003))` will give you the expected result, but you should use [Decimal](http://docs.python.org/library/decimal.html) if you need precision.

Comment: Note: Use decimal here not only for precision but also for exactness.

Comment: I am not sure, but I perceive "precision" and "exactness" as synonyms, precision being the usual term.

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precision_vs._accuracy - the numbers discussed are very precise but the problem discussed is that they are inaccurate.

Answer (score 3):

float (and double) do not have infinite precision. Naturally, rounding errors occur when you operate on them.

Answer (score 2):

This is a [Python FAQ](http://www.python.org/doc/faq/general/#why-are-floating-point-calculations-so-inaccurate)

The same question comes up [quite regularly in comp.lang.python](http://groups.google.co.uk/group/comp.lang.python/search?hl=en&group=comp.lang.python&q=floating+point+faq) also.

I think reason it is a FAQ is that because python is perfect in all other respects ;-), we expect it to perform arithmetic perfectly - just like we were taught at school.  However, as anyone who has done a numerical methods course will tell you, floating point numbers are a very long way from perfect.

[Decimal](http://docs.python.org/library/decimal.html) is a good alternative and if you want more speed and more options [gmpy](http://gmpy.sourceforge.net/) is great too.

Answer (score 0):

by this example
I think this is an error in Python when you devide

```
    >>> print(int(((48/5.0)-9)*5))
    2
```

the easy way, I solve this problem by this

```
    >>> print(int(round(((48/5.0)-9)*5,2)))
    3﻿
```

Comment: How is this relevant?