# What is float('123.987') in Python?

Tags: python, floating-point

It's ***123.98699999999999*** !

Why is that?

Comment: Unbelievable how often this question comes up. How would you represent the rational number 123987/1000?

Comment: GregS: Fraction(123987, 1000) ...?

Comment: -1: There are about a thousand duplicates for this.

Comment: @RadiantHex: Please don't remove the question body once it is answered. It makes it difficult for other readers to understand the context for the answers.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python float - str - float weirdness](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1778368/python-float-str-float-weirdness) and probably a few hundred others.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [Python FAQ](http://www.python.org/doc/faq/general/#why-are-floating-point-calculations-so-inaccurate) and [tutorial](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/floatingpoint) address this issue pretty well, I think.  More generally, both are excellent resources, well worth your time to browse if you have any interest in Python!-)

Answer (score 14):

See [Why can't decimal numbers be represented exactly in binary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1089018/why-cant-decimal-numbers-be-represented-exactly-in-binary)

Answer (score 3):

This has changed in/since [Python 3.1](http://docs.python.org/py3k/whatsnew/3.1.html#other-language-changes).

See also: [issue 1580](http://bugs.python.org/issue1580)

---

To your (already deleted) addition: Use the [decimal package](http://docs.python.org/library/decimal.html).

Comment: The conversion of float to string has changed, but not the conversion from string to float.

Comment: @dan04: What do you mean? `float('0.2') == float(0.2)`

Comment: `repr(0.2)` used to be `'0.20000000000000001'`.  Now it's just `'0.2'`.