# Why is (double)0.6f > (double)(6/10f)?

Tags: c#

This is what happens on my computer:

```
(double)(float)0.6
= 0.60000002384185791

(double)0.6f
= 0.60000002384185791

(double)(6/10f)
= 0.6

(double)(float)(6/10f)
= 0.6
```

6/10f  is also a float，how come it can be precisely 0.6?
In my mind (double)(6/10f) should also be 0.60000002384185791.
Can someone help explain this? thanks!

Comment: By the way in Java, the result is 0.6000000238418579 for all of the above.

Comment: I'm using immediate window. I've tested in program, they are not equal. So it not a matter of foramtting.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1778368/python-float-str-float-weirdness

Comment: @Thomas, IEEE754 double precision lets you specify _much_ closer to 0.6 with the `0x3fe3333333333333` value.

Comment: Well, at least it's consistent on [mono](http://ideone.com/y99Dt) (0.600000023841858 for all 4)

Comment: I'm guessing the binary representation of these two are different: "(float)(6/10.0)" and "(float)(6/10.0f)"

Comment: In general, don't ever try to expect floats/doubles to be equal.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why are floating point numbers inaccurate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21895756/why-are-floating-point-numbers-inaccurate)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, its important to bear in mind that `0.6` cannot be accurately represented as a `float` however it *can* be accurately represented as a `double` (the inaccuracies of floating point arithmetic are well documented, if its not clear why `0.6` cannot be accurately represented as a float, try [this link](http://effbot.org/pyfaq/why-are-floating-point-calculations-so-inaccurate.htm))

The reason why you are seeing the above behaviour is down to the compiler - if you take a look at the compiled assembly in reflector then whats going on here is a little clearer:

(**UPDATE** I've changed the code so that it doesn't use `Console.WriteLine`, as I realised that the compiler was choosing an overload for you, which confused the situation)

```
// As written in source
var j = (double)(float)0.6;
var k = (double)0.6f;
var l = (double)(6/10f);
var m = (double)(float)(6/10f);

// Code as seen by Reflector
double j = 0.60000002384185791;
double k = 0.60000002384185791;
double l = 0.6;
double m = 0.6;
```

Why the compiler chooses to compile in this particular way is beyond me (fyi, this is all with optimisations turned off)

Some interesting other cases:

```
// Code
var a = 0.6;
var b = (double)0.6;
var c = 0.6f;
var d = (float)0.6;

var e = 6 / 10;
var f = 6 / (10f);
var g = (float)(6 / 10);
var h = 6 / 10f;
var i = (double)6 / 10;
// Prints out 0.60000002384185791

double n = (float)0.6;
double o = f;

// As seen by Reflector
double a = 0.6;
double b = 0.6;
float c = 0.6f;
float d = 0.6f;

int e = 0;
float f = 0.6f;
float g = 0f;
float h = 0.6f;
double i = 0.6;

double n = 0.60000002384185791;
double o = f;
```

The compiler only seems to do the above trick in a couple of special cases, why it does this only when casting to a double is completely beyond me!

The rest of the time it seems to do some trickery to make floating point arithmetic *seem* to work where in fact it normally wouldn't.

Comment: Interestingly enough, if you use `float`, all of them will print 0.6 (as seen on [ideone](http://ideone.com/2lvBI), also tested with Visual C#)

Comment: Thanks everybody, I think its indeed a compiler specific issue.

Comment: Also I found that: float float3 = 0.6f; int int1 = 6; float1 = 10; Assert.IsTrue(int1 / float1 >= float3);//fails, In my code float3 is an argument!

Comment: 0.6 CANNOT be accurately represented as a double.

Comment: @Rick is right, and this answer is wrong.  3/5 repeats infinitely in base 2, so it can not be represented exactly as a `double` or as *any* finite binary number.

Answer (score 2):

It appears to be rounding the result. Are you displaying the result with the necessary digits of precision? You can use [this c# class](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/DoubleConverter.cs) from Jon Skeet to get the exact numeric representation of the result printed out.

Note that `ToString()` will not always print all of the digits, nor will the Visual Studio debugger.

Answer (score 1):

If I were a betting man, I'd say the difference is in where the coercion is happening. In the latter two examples (the ones with 6/10f), there are two literals that are both whole numbers (the integer 6 and the float 10.00000000...). The division appears to be happening after the coercion, at least in the compiler you're using. In the first two examples, you have a fractional float literal (0.6) which cannot be adequately expressed as a binary value within the mantissa of a float. Coercing that value to a double cannot repair the damage that was already done.

In the environments that are producing completely consistent results, the division is occurring before the coercion to double (the 6 will be coerced to a float for the division to match the 10, the division is carried out in float space, then the result is coerced to a double).

Comment: You can always take a boo at what's happened by using ildasm and looking at the intermediate assembly created.