# Why are some floating point numbers accurately represented in C#?

Tags: c#, floating-point

Inspired by [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3748768/why-is-double0-6f-double6-10f), the following doesn't do what I'd expect it to:

```
float myFloat = 0.6;
Console.WriteLine(myFloat);
// Output: 0.6
```

I'd expect the above to print out `0.60000002384185791` (the floating point representation of `0.6`) - clearly there is some mechanism here which is making this work when in fact it shouldn't (although as you can see from the linked question it sometimes doesn't work)

What is this mechanism and how does it work?

Comment: @NullUserExceptiuon - true, I'll alter the title.

Comment: The default output for a float is 7 significant digits.  0.6000000 and then the trailing zeroes are removed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look at the implementation of `Console.WriteLine`, you'll see that it ends up calling `ToString` on the value with a default `FormatProvider`. I.e. the result you're seeing is how the number appears when formatted using this format provider.

While it doesn't explain the details of how the result is produced, it does show that `Console.WriteLine` goes through some formatting of the value before printing it.

Answer (score 3):

I would guess the WriteLine overload that takes a float does rounding when converting it to a string...

Comment: If you don't want to round it, use something like this:  Console.WriteLine(m.ToString ("F8",CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));

where F represents fixed point

For more information see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx#FFormatString

Answer (score 0):

0.6 can't be represented under IEEE754 floats. It sits between 0.599999964237213134765625 (0x3f199999) and 0.600000083446502685546875 (0x3f19999b). The round-to-nearest mode yields 0.60000002384185791015625 (0x3f19999a) which is what WriteLine is printing.

You have to either use a higher precision floating point representation (double) or limit the number of decimal places the WriteLine prints:

```
float f = 0.6; Console.WriteLine("{0:N6}", f);
```

Comment: The OP is aware of float inaccuracy, and wonders why the output **is** 0.6 :)