# Why am I getting the wrong result when using float?

Tags: c#, floating-point

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Why is (double)0.6f > (double)(6/10f)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3748768/why-is-double0-6f-double6-10f)
>   [Why is floating point arithmetic in C# imprecise?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/753948/why-is-floating-point-arithmetic-in-c-imprecise)

I have the following code in C#:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace StackOverflow
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            float num1 = 17.03F;
            float num2 = 17F;
            float result = num1 - num2;
            Console.WriteLine(result);
        }
    }
}
```

The code works fine but I am not getting the expected result. Can someone explain why this is happening?

Comment: What do you expect? What do you get?

Comment: Your expectations of floating point arithmetic are incorrect. See the question linked from the comment above, or any number of other questions tagged floating-point. Also see http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/FloatingPoint.aspx

Comment: What result are you expecting and what result are you getting?

Comment: @Jon, both questions have the wrong names, thus - low search relevance.

Comment: Expected result should be 0.03 but i am getting 0.03000069

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess you are refering to deviations cause by [Floating point arithmetics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point). You can read about in in the provided link.

If you really need to make the calculation 100% accurate, you can use `decimal` instead of `float`.

Answer (score 1):

Because you are using `float`. Float is an extremely approximate value. Always use it with an Epsilon (maximum error allowance) when comparing.

I am guessing you are getting result = 0.02999999?

Answer (score 1):

Floating point maths is likely to contain rounding approximations, see the many duplicate questions on this site, or read here:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point

Answer (score 1):

What about this? : [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)