# c#: sum of two double numbers problem

Tags: c#, double, decimal

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why is floating point arithmetic in C# imprecise?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/753948/why-is-floating-point-arithmetic-in-c-imprecise)

Hi. I've got following problem:

```
43.65+61.11=104.75999999999999
```

for decimal is correct:

```
(decimal)43.65+(decimal)61.11=104.76
```

Why result for double is wrong?

Comment: There are many questions dealing with the issue of double not bing able to represent all numbers. If you search for [c# and double](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=c%23+double) you will find quite a few. This one is good for instance: [Why is (double)0.6f > (double)(6/10f)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3748768/why-is-double0-6f-double6-10f). Also, [Jon Skeet's article](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/FloatingPoint.aspx) is worth reading.

Comment: You don't need to cast to decimal. Just use "m" suffix. For example, 43.6m + 61.11m identifies both literals as "decimal type values".

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This question and its answers are a wealth of info on this - [Difference between decimal, float and double in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/618535/what-is-the-difference-between-decimal-float-and-double-in-c)

To quote:

> - For values which are "naturally exact
>     decimals" it's good to use decimal.
>     This is usually suitable for any
>     concepts invented by humans: financial
>     values are the most obvious example,
>     but there are others too. Consider the
>     score given to divers or ice skaters,
>     for example.
> - For values which are more artefacts of
>     nature which can't really be measured
>     exactly anyway, float/double are more
>     appropriate. For example, scientific
>     data would usually be represented in
>     this form. Here, the original values
>     won't be "decimally accurate" to start
>     with, so it's not important for the
>     expected results to maintain the
>     "decimal accuracy". Floating binary
>     point types are much faster to work
>     with than decimals.

Answer (score 3):

It isn't exactly wrong. It's the closest decimal representation to the binary floating-point number that results from the sum.

The problem is that IEEE floats cannot represent 43.65 + 61.11 exactly, due to the use of a binary mantissa. Some systems (such as Python 2.7 and Visual C++'s standard I/O libraries) will round to the simplest decimal that resolves to the same binary, and will print the expected 104.76. But all these systems arrive at exactly the same answer internally.

Interestingly, decimal notation can finitely represent any finite binary fraction, whereas the opposite doesn't hold. If humans had two fingers and computers used ten-state memory, we wouldn't have this problem. :-)

Answer (score 3):

Short answer: floating point representation (such as "double") is inherently inaccurate. So is fixed point (such as "decimal"), but the inaccuracy in fixed-point representation is of a different kind. Here's one short explanation: http://effbot.org/pyfaq/why-are-floating-point-calculations-so-inaccurate.htm

You can google for "floating point inaccuracy" or so for more.

Answer (score 2):

Because double uses a fractional model. Any number < 1 is expressed in the form of x / y. Given that information, some numbers can only be approximated. Use decimal, not double for high precision calculations.

See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_precision_floating-point_format) for some light reading :)

Comment: Decimals are fractions. The problem is that the typical machine representation is a binary representation, which cannot represent all decimals with a finite expansion.

Comment: decimal is best choice for money type

Answer (score 2):

It comes down to the fact that floats are stored as binary floats, and like in base 10, there are some numbers which can't be stored without truncation. Take for example 1/3rd in base 10, that is .3 recurring. The numbers you are dealing with, when converted to binary are recurring.

I disagree that floats or doubles are more or less accurate than decimal representations. They are as accurate as you choose to have precision. They are a different representation however, and different numbers can be expressed wholey than in base 10.

Decimal stores numbers in base 10. That will probably give you the result you expect

Answer (score 1):

Decimal arithmetic is well-suited for base-10 representations of numbers, as base-10 numbers can be exactly represented in decimal. (Which is why currency is *always* stored in currency appropriate classes, or stored in `int` with a scaling factor to represent 'pennies' or 'pence' or other similar decimal currency.)

[IEEE-754 Binary numbers cannot calculate with `.1` or `.01`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point#Accuracy_problems) accurately. So floating point formats *approximate* the inputs, and you get approximate outputs back, which is perfectly acceptable *for what floating point was designed to handle* -- physical simulations, scientific data, and fast numerical mathematical methods.

Note this simple program and output:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    float f, g;
    double d, e;
    long double l, m;

    f=0.1;
    g=f*f;
    d=0.1;
    e=d*d;
    l=0.1;
    m=l*l;
    printf("%40.40f, %40.40f, %40.40Lf\n", g, e, m);
    return 0;
}

$ ./fp
0.0100000007078051567077636718750000000000,
0.0100000000000000019428902930940239457414,
0.0100000000000000011102569059430467124372
```

All three possibilities don't give the exact answer, `0.01`, but they do give numbers that are quite close to the answer.

But use decimal arithmetic for currency.

Comment: Binary numbers *can* represent 0.1 or 0.000000000000001 accurately. Read about fixed-point representation, then read about floating-point representation, then answer such questions.

Answer (score 0):

Really? The code below returned **104.76** as expected:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        double d1 = 43.65;
        double d2 = 61.11;
        double d3 = d1 + d2;
        Console.WriteLine(d3);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

whereas the below code returned **104.76000213623**

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        float d1 = 43.65f;
        float d2 = 61.11f;
        double d3 = d1 + d2;
        Console.WriteLine(d3);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Check if you are converting from float to double which may have caused this issue.