# Floating point precision while using Python's max()

Tags: python, floating-point, precision, floating-accuracy

Why so?

```
>>> max(2, 2.01)
2.0099999999999998
```

Comment: Because that's how floating point numbers work: http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

Comment: Take a look at [float-str-float wierdness](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1778368/python-float-str-float-weirdness) on StackOverflow

Comment: Thanks.Just getting the hang of things..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The number 2.01 represented in binary is:

```
b10.00000010100011111100001010001111110000101000111111000010100011111100...
```

The computer uses only a finite number of digits to store floating-point values, but the binary representation of 2.01 requires infinitely many digits; as a result, it is *rounded* to the closest representable value:

```
b10.000000101000111111000010100011111100001010001111110
```

Expressed in decimal, this number is exactly:

```
2.0099999999999997868371792719699442386627197265625
```

When you print it out, it is rounded a second time to seventeen decimal digits, giving:

```
2.0099999999999998
```

Answer (score 3):

Floating point numbers do not encode exact values, but approximations.  The result is essentially the next nearest floating point number to the real number you entered.

http://docs.python.org/tutorial/floatingpoint.html

Answer (score 2):

because:

```
>>> 2.01
2.0099999999999998
```

it's the way floating point numbers are stored

Answer (score 0):

Floating point roundoff. Its trying to say 2.01 but can't express it exactly as a floating point number so its doing the best it can.