# Are there any limitations when going from binary to decimal (just as when going from decimal to binary)?

Tags: math, language-agnostic, floating-point

As we all know, [not all decimal numbers can be represented in binary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5701317/floating-point-precision-while-using-pythons-max) (with a finite number of digits).

I'm wondering, can all (finite) binary numbers be represented using (a finite number of) decimal digits? I suspect so, since all "primitives" in binary ("0.5", "0.125", etc) can be represented with a finite number of decimal digits.

So, my question is the following: What characterizes a "compatible base-change"? I.e., what are the mathematical properties that hold for "*Base 2 → Base 10*" but does not hold for "*Base 10 → Base 2*"?

(Put formally: What properties must *N* and *M* have, in order to ensure that all finite Base-N numbers have a corresponding finite Base-M number?)

Comment: +1 nice well-written question that addresses a topic many people are confused about.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If *n* is a binary fraction, then *n* = *a* / 2<sup>*k*</sup> for integers *a* and *k*.

That means that *n* = (*a* · 5<sup>*k*</sup>) / (2<sup>*k*</sup> · 5<sup>*k*</sup>) = (*a* · 5<sup>*k*</sup>) / 10<sup>*k*</sup>

So every binary fraction is a decimal fraction.

In the general case, every fraction to base *N* is also a fraction to base *M* if and only if *N* divides *M*<sup>*k*</sup> for some *k* (or, equivalently, if every prime factor of *N* is also a prime factor of *M*). An argument similar to the one I gave above for 2 and 10 handles the "if" direction. For the "only if" direction, here's a sketch proof for you to fill in: suppose that 1 / *N* = *a* / *M*<sup>*k*</sup>, then *M*<sup>*k*</sup> = *a* · *N*, therefore *N* divides *M*<sup>*k*</sup>.

So binary can be converted to decimal without loss because 2 is factor of 10, but decimal cannot be converted to binary without loss, because 5 is a factor of 10 but not a factor of 2.

Comment: I can't immediately see the relation between fractions and finite numbers. 1/3 for instance can't be represented using a finite number of decimal digits.

Comment: It's just terminology: "binary fraction" means "a fraction with an exact representation in binary" and "decimal fraction" means "a fraction with an exact representation in decimal".

Comment: Aha, I read your answer again with this in mind and the answer makes a lot of sense. :-)

Comment: Haha -- the sketch proof hides more details than I thought on first read-through. +1 for graceful glossing.