# Python weird subtraction result

Tags: python

this is my dictionary:

```
weights = {
71.03711 : "A",
156.10111 : "R",
114.04293 : "N",
115.02694 : "D",
103.00919 : "C",
129.04259 : "E",
128.05858 : "Q",
57.02146 : "G",
137.05891 : "H",
113.08406 : "I",
128.09496 : "K",
131.04049 : "M",
147.06841 : "F",
97.05276 : "P",
87.03203 : "S",
101.04768 : "T",
186.07931 : "W",
163.06333 : "Y",
99.06841 : "V",
}
```

Now I make a calculation:

```
a = (129.08346 - 15.99940) # a = 113.08406 = "I" (in dictionary)
```

Then:

```
sequence += weights[a]
```

ERROR:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "task2.py", line 43, in <module>
    sequence += weights[a]
KeyError: 113.08406000000001
```

Why does he attach that 1 ? :( I need the value 113.08406 !

Comment: possible duplicate of [Floating point precision while using Python's max()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5701317/floating-point-precision-while-using-pythons-max)

Comment: This is a floating point precision issue.  I'm sure there are lots of dupes around ... Basically, the problem is that floating point numbers make bad dictionary keys because it's hard to get exactly the right float from computations.

Comment: Floating point arithmetic isn't very precise. There are only so many floating point values that can be stored, and if your subtraction doesn't exactly hit one, the closest one is taken. Instead of using floats for your dictionary keys, try just multiplying each by 100000 to give integer keys, which won't have this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Pass the result to the `round()` function:

```
a = round(129.08346 - 15.99940, 5) # second argument is number of decimals
```

Output:

`113.08406`