# float deviation in python list

Tags: python, floating-point, rounding

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Python float - str - float weirdness](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1778368/python-float-str-float-weirdness)

I run the following code in python on codepad.org:

```
num = 1.6
print num
list = [num]
print list
num2 = list[0]
print num2
```

And I get the following output:

```
1.6
[1.6000000000000001]
1.6
```

Why the tiny deviation in the list?

Comment: Good thing you found the `floating-point` tag. Go read some high-voted questions with that tag, no use in repeating the same mantra every time someone is tripped up by them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`list.__str__` calls `repr` on its elements, where as print calls `str`:

```
>>> str(1.6)
'1.6'
>>> repr(1.6)
'1.6000000000000001'
```

Since floating point numbers are not guaranteed to be exact (and cannot be exact for values that can't be expressed as a * 2<sup>b</sup> for integers a,b), both representations are correct, or, in other words:

```
>>> 1.6 == 1.6000000000000001
True
```