# Python floating point number comparison

Tags: python, floating-point

I'm just reviewing some basics of Python and there's a tricky problem about comparing floating point numbers.

```
2.2 * 3.0 == 6.6
3.3 * 2.0 == 6.6
```

I thought these should both return a False. However, the second one gave me a True.
[image]

Please help me here. Thanks!

Comment: You shall never compare two float numbers by `==`. Use `abs(a-b) < Threshold` if you really want to.

Comment: @Steve Yes, I am aware of that, but still thanks for your note :)

Comment: @Steve: A correct comparison is more complicated than this, since the precision of floats is a number of digits, not an absolute numerical value. Something like `abs(a-b) <= rel_prec * max(abs(a), abs(b))` is better (with rel_prec close to 1e-16, for instance, for Python's double precision floats). In addition to this, the case of a zero value should be handled too. I did not fully check this, but the following might work: `abs(a-b) <= rel_prec * (max(abs(a), abs(b)) if a != 0 != b else 1)`.

Comment: This isn't specific to Python. The same problem occurs for floats in any language.

Comment: I can understand expecting them to both return `True` if you didn't understand how floats and rounding errors work, but what could possibly make you expect them both to return `False`?

Comment: @Steve: Huh?  You can compare two floating-point numbers for equality using `==`.  It works correctly.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is floating point math broken?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Comment: @tmyklebu: That depends on what you mean by "correctly". If you want `2.2 * 3.0 == 6.6` to be `False` because the closest IEEE-double binary floating-point fractions to `2.2` and `3.0` do not multiply to `6.6`, then yes, `==` works correctly. If you want it to be `True` because the real numbers `2.2` and `3.0` do multiply to `6.6`, then `==` does not work correctly. Or, if you want it to be `True` because the real numbers `2.2` and `3.0`, when rounded to binary floats, are within the appropriate propagated error range of `6.6`, then `==` does not work correctly.

Comment: @EOL, you are right. The realistic is more complicated.

Comment: @abarnert: If you want `==` to return `True` for two things that aren't equal, you need to adjust your idea of what `==` should do.

Comment: @tmyklebu: Which is effectively what Steve said, and you disagreed with. If you want to check whether the results of two floating-point computations are representations of the same number modulo rounding error, you should not be using `==`, because that's not what `==` means (nor what it should mean).

Comment: @abarnert: No, Steve said "don't use `==` to compare two floating-point numbers."  That's horrible advice and it enforces unjustified superstitions.

Comment: @tmyklebu: OK, in what situation is checking the result of a computation with `==` (e.g., checking `2.2 * 3.0 == 6.6`) a useful thing to do?

Comment: @abarnert: Whenever you want to check for equality of floating-point numbers, you use the operator that checks for equality of floating-point numbers.

Comment: @tmyklebu: And when is that? Almost always, when you think you want to check for equality of floating-point numbers, you're wrong, and you do not. If you're in a situation where you really _do_ want to check, you know better. Steve's advice is not superstition or harmful; it's a rule of thumb that people should follow until they run into a situation where they say, "Hold on, here I really care about the N-bit binary fraction" (or "… about the bit pattern" or whatever), at which point they'll understand that rules have exceptions.

Comment: @abarnert: I prefer the rule "understand your tools before using them in serious code" to some hodgepodge of superstitions about `goto` and floating-point numbers.  Situations where `==` is appropriate:  If you can prove no roundoff error will occur, you use `==`.  For instance, Graham's scan can be implemented correctly with `double`s if your points have, say, integer coordinates in [-2^24, 2^24].  The cases where you *can't* use `==` are scarier, since it means you probably need to fall back to MPFR to see whether your predicate is actually true or actually false.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This might be illuminating:

```
>>> float.hex(2.2 * 3.0)
'0x1.a666666666667p+2'
>>> float.hex(3.3 * 2.0)
'0x1.a666666666666p+2'
>>> float.hex(6.6)
'0x1.a666666666666p+2'
```

Although they are all displayed in decimal as `6.6`, when you inspect the internal representation, two of them are represented in the same way, while one of them is not.

Comment: But they're _not_ all displayed in decimal as `6.6`. In 3.x, `print(2.2 * 3.0)` or just `2.2 * 3.0` will show `6.6000000000000005`. In 2.x, the `print` will truncate, but just `2.2 * 3.0` will still show `6.6000000000000005`. So, this is simpler to see than the answer implies.

Answer (score 3):

In order to complete Amadan's good answer, here is a more obvious way of seeing that 2.2*3. and 3.3*2. are not represented by the same float: in a Python shell,

```
>>> 2.2 * 3.
6.6000000000000005
>>> 3.3 * 2.
6.6
```

In fact, the Python shell displays the *representation* of numbers, which by definition should allow the corresponding float to be correctly built back from the representation, so you see the numerical approximation of 2.2*3 that Python does. The fact that 2.2*3. != 3.3*2. is obvious when seeing all the necessary digits, like above.

Comment: The part about the representation vs. the friendly version is relevant to Python 2.x, but not to 3.x. In 3.x, `print(2.2*3.)` will still give you `6.6000000000000005`. In 3.x, both `str` and `repr` return the shortest string that will evaluate back to the same `float`; in 2.x, `str` truncates to a platform-specific number of digits, while `repr` doesn't.

Comment: Interesting. There was no "part about the representation vs the friendly version" before your comment, though. :D

Comment: Reference about Python 3's `str` change: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25898733/why-does-strfloat-return-more-digits-in-python-3-than-python-2.

Answer (score 0):

It is also obvious that `3.3 * 2.0` is numerically identical to `6.6`. The latter computation is nothing more than an increment of the binary exponent as it is the result of a multiplication with a power of two. You can see this in the following:

```
    | s exponent    significant
----+-------------------------------------------------------------------
1.1 | 0 01111111111 0001100110011001100110011001100110011001100110011010
2.2 | 0 10000000000 0001100110011001100110011001100110011001100110011010
3.3 | 0 10000000000 1010011001100110011001100110011001100110011001100110
6.6 | 0 10000000001 1010011001100110011001100110011001100110011001100110
```

Above you see the binary representation of the floating point numbers `3.3` and `6.6`. The only difference in the two numbers is the exponent since they are only multiplied with two. We know that IEEE-754 will:

- approximate a decimal number with the smallest numerical error
- can represent all integers up to `2^53` exactly (for binary64)

So since `2.0` is exactly representable, a multiplication with this number will be nothing more than a change in the exponent. So all the following will create the same floating point numbers:

```
6.6 == 0.825 * 16.0 == 1.65 * 4.0 == 3.3*2.0 == 13.2 * 0.5 == ...
```

Does this mean that `2.2*3.0` is different from `6.6` because of the significant? No, this was just due to rounding errors in the multiplication.

An example where it would have worked would have been `5.5*2.0 == 2.2*5.0 == 11.0`. Here the rounding was favourable