# Is there a way to show correct float value?

Tags: python, python-2.7, floating-point, division

Is there a way to show float value in Python 2 like Python 3 does?

Code:

```
text = "print('hello, world')"

step = 100.0 / len(text)
result = 0.0

for _ in text:
    result += step

print result
print step
print result == 100.0
```

Python 2.7.9

```
100.0
4.7619047619
False
```

Python 3.4.3

```
99.99999999999997
4.761904761904762
False
```

I'm interested in result variable. not in step. Sorry for insufficient explanation what I want. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`repr` shows more digits (I'm guessing just enough to reproduce the same float):

```
>>> print result
100.0
>>> print repr(result)
99.99999999999997
>>> result
99.99999999999997

>>> print step
4.7619047619
>>> print repr(step)
4.761904761904762
>>> step
4.761904761904762
```

Comment: Strange behavior for built-in type as for me, but at least it works.

Comment: I guess the Python makers agree with you, given that they apparently "fixed" it in Python 3 :-)

Answer (score 2):

Running your code in Python2 or Python3 calculates the *same* value for `result` and `step`. The only difference is in the way the float gets printed.

In Python2.7 (or Python3) you can control the number of digits shown after the decimal by using `str.format`:

```
print('{:.14f}'.format(result))
```

prints

```
99.99999999999997
```

Comment: Whoops, I didn't explain what I want carefully. Question updated.

Comment: *saw that you changed your answer* I can't reformat `result` with `.format` because Python 2 shows that variable is equal to 100.0, not to 99.999.. and it's frustrating

Comment: Yes, but at the same time Python2 shows `result` is 100.0. I see this behavior frustrating, so I want Python 2 to show this value as 99.99 as Python 3 do. That's the question.

Answer (score 0):

Storing decimal floating point numbers in binary causes rounding issues when representing them in decimal. This is a fact of (computer programming) life in any language, but Python2 deals with this differently than python3 (see: [25898733](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25898733/)).

Using [string formatting](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-string-syntax) you can make your script produce the same output in python2 as in python3 and also have a more human readable output:

```
text = "print('hello, world')"
step = 100.0 / len(text)
result = 0.0

for _ in text:
    result += step

print ("{0:.1f}".format(result))
print ("{0:.1f}".format(step))

print ("{0:.1f}".format(result) == "100.0")  # kludge to compare floats
```

**Output**:

```
100.0
4.8
True
```

Comment: It's all good until you don't want to compare this variable to another. It is possible to write `float("{0:.1f}".format(result))`, but it's totally ugly.