# Not able get exact str(float) result of python 2 in python 3

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.6, six

I'm trying to port some py2 code to py3, and I'd like to somehow reproduce the exact string representation of a floating number that py2 *would have* returned, but in python 3.

e.g.

```
from __future__ import print_function

a = 1.5 * 0.4
string = str(a)
print(string)
```

In python3, the output is `0.6000000000000001` , vs python2, where the output is `0.6`, and I understand why:

[Why does str(float) return more digits in Python 3 than Python 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25898733/why-does-strfloat-return-more-digits-in-python-3-than-python-2)

However, is there a way where I can faithfully reproduce (in python3) what `str(a)` *would have been* (e.g. same behavior in py2 and py3), for arbitrary values of `a`?

I tried this

```
import six
a = 1.5 * 0.4
string = str(a)
if six.PY3:
    string = '{:.12g}'.format(a)
print(string)
```

The above "almost" works, but in the case `a = 5` , we'll get different output (`5.0` for py2 and `5` for py3)

Comment: Try `f` instead of `g`.

Comment: i think that'l always get me 12 decimal places, e.g. 0.600000000000

Comment: You could cut the superfluous zeros of the `f` formatting with something like `while string[-1] in ('0', '.'): string = string[:-1]` (not exactly with that code!).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem comes from the fact that as the same way some fractions are note easily represented in decimal form (for example 1/3 = 0.33333333…), some fractions are not easily represented in binary form (for example 1/3 = 0.01010101…). But if you want to have as consistent results as a decimal numbers, consider looking at the [decimal](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html) module (which is available in Python 2.7 and 3). You could have something like this:

```py
from decimal import Decimal

a = Decimal('1.5') * Decimal('0.4')
result = str(a)
print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> a = 1.5 * 0.4
>>> print(f'{a:.1f}')
0.6
```

Comment: `a = 1.55; print(f'{a:.1f}')` gives `1.6`. This is probably not desired.

Comment: yep, i certainly know how to format floats to arbitrary precision in either py2 or py3 , but what i dont know how to do is reproduce whatever py2's `str(a)` is doing.