# float64 with pandas to_csv

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I'm reading a CSV with float numbers like this:

```
Bob,0.085
Alice,0.005
```

And import into a dataframe, and write this dataframe to a new place

```
df = pd.read_csv(orig)
df.to_csv(pandasfile)
```

Now this `pandasfile` has:

```
Bob,0.085000000000000006
Alice,0.0050000000000000001
```

What happen? maybe I have to cast to a different type like float32 or something?

Im using **pandas 0.9.0** and **numpy 1.6.2**.

Comment: Welcome to floating point numbers.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1778368/python-float-str-float-weirdness

Comment: I created an issue to examine in a bit more detail here: http://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/2069 EDIT: If you can, please put a standalone reproduction of the problem on the GitHub issue. I'm not able to reproduce it.

Answer (score 247, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, it is a general floating point problem.

However you can use the `float_format` key word of `to_csv` to hide it:

```
df.to_csv('pandasfile.csv', float_format='%.3f')
```

or, if you don't want 0.0001 to be rounded to zero:

```
df.to_csv('pandasfile.csv', float_format='%g')
```

will give you:

```
Bob,0.085
Alice,0.005
```

in your output file.

For an explanation of `%g`, see [Format Specification Mini-Language](https://docs.python.org/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language).

Comment: I got an error `TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'float_format'`

Comment: If someone has the same error as @wander95, you probably need to update `pandas` to a newer version.

Comment: If you use `%.3f` you won't just get 0.0001 rounded to zero, but also get 0.1 encoded as 0.100

Answer (score 19):

**UPDATE:** Answer was accurate at time of writing, and floating point precision is still not something you get by default with to_csv/read_csv (precision-performance tradeoff; defaults favor performance).

Nowadays there is [the `float_format` argument available for `pandas.DataFrame.to_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) and [the `float_precision` argument available for `pandas.from_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html).

The original is still worth reading to get a better grasp on the problem.

---

It was a bug in pandas, not only in "to_csv" function, but in "read_csv" too. It's not a general floating point issue, despite it's true that *floating point arithmetic* is a subject which demands some care from the programmer. This article below clarifies a bit this subject:

```
http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/floatingpoint.html
```

A classic one-liner which shows the "problem" is ...

```
>>> 0.1 + 0.1 + 0.1
0.30000000000000004
```

... which does not display 0.3 as one would expect. On the other hand, if you handle the calculation using *fixed point arithmetic* and only in the last step you employ *floating point arithmetic*, it will work as you expect. See this:

```
>>> (1 + 1 + 1)  * 1.0 / 10
0.3
```

If you desperately need to circumvent this problem, I recommend you create another CSV file which contains all figures as integers, for example multiplying by 100, 1000 or other factor which turns out to be convenient. Inside your application, read the CSV file as usual and you will get those integer figures back. Then convert those values to floating point, dividing by the same factor you multiplied before.

Answer (score 5):

I have encountered this problem and this is the solution I have found.
(I tried the other solution, but it didn't work correctly.)

First, try to round to the desired decimals and then export to csv.

Just try the following :

```
df = df.astype(float).round(3)
df.to_csv('pandasfile.csv')
```