# Pandas to_csv export giving wrong values in a dataframe

Tags: python-2.7, csv, pandas, numpy, floating-point

I am using pandas and have imported two csv.

df1 is

[image]

df2 is

[image]

The data type of df2 is

[image]

When i am doing some manipulation on df1 and df2 :

```
df3= pd.merge(df1, df2, how='left', on=['Origin City Code', 'DC'])
```

and then export it to csv

```
df3.to_csv("test.CSV")
```

then the sum of all the values under column "Volume" is NOT matching with sum of the values under columns of original df2. In-fact the sum in df3 is coming out to be more. I believe the issue is coming up due to floating point numbers. But is there any way to resolve it ?? I have gone through the following links but my question remains unanswered.

https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/2069

[float64 with pandas to_csv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12877189/float64-with-pandas-to-csv)

[reading and writing csv in pandas changes cell values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15879992/reading-and-writing-csv-in-pandas-changes-cell-values?noredirect=1&lq=1)

[Wrong decimal calculations with pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18147230/wrong-decimal-calculations-with-pandas?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Here is the code files i am using:https://www.dropbox.com/s/kjpnhl7qtojes92/sample.rar?dl=0

Comment: Do you have repeat `['Origin City Code', 'DC']` rows in `df1`?  That would cause there to be repeat volumes in the merged DataFrame, explaining the larger sum.

Comment: @root .. no repeated value in df1. I checked

Comment: I don't mean repeats as a whole, just on the `['Origin City Code', 'DC']` subset, i.e. `df.duplicated(subset=['Origin City Code', 'DC']).any()`.  How much is the sum off by?  Can you provide a reproducible example?  I can't reproduce the error with the data you've shown.

Comment: Can you show the values of the sums in question? How *much* more is the sum for `df3` than the sum for `df2`?

Comment: And what are `df2.shape` and `df3.shape`? Do the two dataframes have the same number of rows?

Comment: @Mark: df2.shape=(66179,7) and df3.shape = (331810, 5).. df2 has sum = 733775
and df 3 = 736557

Comment: So `df3` has many more rows than `df2`. Why do you expect the volume sums to be equal? BTW, that size difference in the results is very unlikely to be the result of floating-point error.

Comment: @MarkDickinson and root.. i have shared with you the sample files and codes ( Dropbox link updated in my original post). could you please take a look..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked at your files, as @root was saying above, in df1 the combination of `Origin City Code` and `DC` are not unique. For instance, there are two records with `Origin City Code` = GGN and `DC` = ASA.

If you want to check it out you can run the following code:

```
df1[df1.duplicated(subset=['Origin City Code', 'DC'], keep=False)].sort_values(['Origin City Code', 'DC'])
```

Here's the head of this output:

[image]

Comment: Nice answer. It's @root who was talking about non-uniqueness, though, not me. (Though I agree with root that it seems likely that's at least part of the issue.)