# Wrong decimal calculations with pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame (df) in pandas with four columns and I want a new column to represent the mean of this four columns: df['mean']= df.mean(1)

```
  1    2    3    4   mean 
NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN      NaN  
5.9  5.4  2.4  3.2    4.225  
0.6  0.7  0.7  0.7    0.675  
2.5  1.6  1.5  1.2    1.700  
0.4  0.4  0.4  0.4    0.400
```

So far so good. But when I save the results to a csv file this is what I found:

```
5.9,5.4,2.4,3.2,4.2250000000000005
0.6,0.7,0.7,0.7,0.6749999999999999
2.5,1.6,1.5,1.2,1.7
0.4,0.4,0.4,0.4,0.4
```

I guess I can force the format in the mean column, but any idea why this is happenning?

I am using winpython with python 3.3.2 and pandas 0.11.0

Comment: I found a good solution here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12877189/float64-with-pandas-to-csv

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the `float_format` parameter:

```
import pandas as pd
import io

content = '''\
1    2    3    4   mean 
NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN      NaN  
5.9  5.4  2.4  3.2    4.225  
0.6  0.7  0.7  0.7    0.675  
2.5  1.6  1.5  1.2    1.700  
0.4  0.4  0.4  0.4    0.400'''

df = pd.read_table(io.BytesIO(content), sep='\s+')
df.to_csv('/tmp/test.csv', float_format='%g', index=False)
```

yields

```
1,2,3,4,mean
,,,,
5.9,5.4,2.4,3.2,4.225
0.6,0.7,0.7,0.7,0.675
2.5,1.6,1.5,1.2,1.7
0.4,0.4,0.4,0.4,0.4
```

Comment: What is '%g', is it the presentation type from [here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language)?

Comment: @AndyHayden: Essentially, yes. But since it is using the percent-sign, I think float_format is using the old-style string format [documented here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting-operations).

Answer (score 2):

The answers seem correct. Floating point numbers cannot be perfectly represented on our systems. There are bound to be some differences. Read [The Floating Point Guide](http://floating-point-gui.de/).

```
>>> a = 5.9+5.4+2.4+3.2
>>> a / 4
4.2250000000000005
```

As you said, you could always format the results if you want to get only a fixed number of points after the decimal.

```
>>> "{:.3f}".format(a/4)
'4.225'
```