# limit number of digits of shapefile attribute in R

Tags: r, shapefile, significant-digits

I need to control the number of significant digits assigned to attributes of an ESRI shapefile that I need to write.

UPDATE: I was using "round()" but it did not seem to work when I checked the result in QGIS Attribute table. The "problem" may in fact be in QGIS for the representation of decimals. Compare the "Form" view and the "Table" view below: digits are rounded in one but not the other.

[Form view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QGTrt.png)

[Table view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ardbh.png)

Comment: Take a look at the suggestions in [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3443687/formatting-decimal-places-in-r)

Comment: Thanks. I was rounding the data in R but in QGis it wasn't showing as such. see update for info.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this was how the file was created but if Geopandas was used to create the shapefile, it has something to do with how geopandas / pandas represents "float" or "float64" types - i.e. precision.

I fixed this problem by not using a shapefile format when saving `to_file`, but Geopackage (GPKG) instead. Otherwise one will have to represent the float as a string, or use the `float_format` argument when saving (not sure if it works for .to_file() ) - see links below.

[float64 with pandas to_csv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12877189/float64-with-pandas-to-csv)
[pandas converting a float remove exponents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51852465/pandas-converting-a-float-remove-exponents)