# Pandas float64 to float 32 ,then the data changes

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a csv file containing some float data.
the code is simple

```
df = pd.read_csv(my_csv_vile)
print(df.iloc[:2,:4]
600663.XSHG  000877.XSHE  600523.XSHG  601311.XSHG
2016-01-04 09:31:00        49.40         8.05        22.79        21.80
2016-01-04 09:32:00        49.55         8.03        22.79        21.75
```

then I convert it to float32 to save memory usage.

```
short_df = df.astype(np.float32)
print(short_df.iloc[:2,:4])
600663.XSHG  000877.XSHE  600523.XSHG  601311.XSHG
2016-01-04 09:31:00    49.400002         8.05    22.790001    21.799999
2016-01-04 09:32:00    49.549999         8.03    22.790001    21.750000
```

the value just changed!
How could I keep the data unchanged?

(I also tried `short_df.round(2)`,but  print still get the same output)

Comment: can you format you code please?

Answer (score 5):

Many decimal floating point numbers can not be accurately represented with a float64 or float32. Review e.g. [The Floating-Point Guide](https://floating-point-gui.de/basic/) if you are unfamiliar with that issue.

Pandas [defaults](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/options.html) to displaying floating points with a precision of 6, and trailing 0s are dropped in the default output.

float64 can accurately represent the example numbers up to (and beyond) precision 6, whereas float32 can not:

```
>>> print("%.6f" % np.float64(49.40))
49.400000

>>> print("%.6f" % np.float32(49.40))
49.400002
```

If you are not interested in the precision beyond the 2nd digit when printing the df, you can set the display precision:

```
pd.set_option('precision', 2)
```

Then you get the same output even with float32s:

```
 >>> df.astype(np.float32)
                     600663.XSHG  000877.XSHE  600523.XSHG  601311.XSHG
2016-01-04 09:31:00        49.40         8.05        22.79        21.80
           09:32:00        49.55         8.03        22.79        21.75
```

If you want to drop everything beyond the 2nd digit when writing back the csv file, use [float_format](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12882439/463796):

```
df.to_csv(file_name, float_format="%.2f")
```