# nice csv floating point output in python

Tags: python, pandas, csv

related to [float64 with pandas to_csv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12877189/float64-with-pandas-to-csv) (but different; here, it is an IEEE issue).  an input csv file is

```
name,value
Alice,0.009
Bob,1.0
```

We want to write an output csv file that looks similar.  of course, 0.009 is not easily storable as an IEEE number, where it really is 0.009000000000000001 .

Not a problem in computations, but now I want to save it nicely.  With a float_format, there are too many digits being forced on every other value in the table.  Without one, the file is painful for my consumers.

```
In [2]: df = pd.read_csv(orig)
    ...: df.to_csv(sys.stdout,float_format="%.5f")
,name,value
0,Alice,0.00900
1,Bob,1.00000

In [3]: df = pd.read_csv(orig)
    ...: df.to_csv(sys.stdout)
,name,value
0,Alice,0.009000000000000001
1,Bob,1.0
```

I could write a function that iterates over all floating point columns in the data frame ("add an epsilon, print at %.15f precision to a string column, then delete trailing zeros after the decimal point, then do the .csv.gz writing").  however, presumably this is a common wish, so it probably already exists somewhere, but I don't know how to find it?!

pointers appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df.to_csv(sys.stdout,float_format="%.15g")
```

Output:

```
,name,value
0,Alice,0.009
1,Bob,1
```

From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language):

> ... insignificant trailing zeros are removed from the significand, and
>   the decimal point is also removed if there are no remaining digits
>   following it.
>
> ... The default precision is 6.