# dtype float 64 can't be read correct in excel

Tags: python, excel

I have a df with a column TOTAALVERKOOP with dtype('float')

row exemple:

```
27  clientname  clientnumber    96.95   2,02211E+13 areacode    adress houdnr NaN   place emailadress   2020    548.55
```

last value is column TOTAALVERKOOP

code to write to csv:

```
df.to_csv("path.csv", index=False)
```

when I write df to csv and open the csv-file in Excel the values can't be read as numbers.

output after reading csv in excel string looks like this

```
 clientname,clientcode,96.95,"2,02211E+13",aeracode,adress,housenr,,place,emailadress,2020,548.5500000000001
```

after the last comma the value should be 548.55

Can't figure out how to solve.

Comment: Try this one, talks about your float issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12877189/float64-with-pandas-to-csv
If you want to use a different separator: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16923281/writing-a-pandas-dataframe-to-csv-file

Comment: What do you see if you open your CSV  file in say Notepad++?