# PYTHON: pandas to_csv is rounding, any way for it to not round?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

I am trying to save values in a dataframe to a csv file. However, pandas to csv is rounding so much that my numbers are really off.
For example, values like 0.00002134566 would be rounded to a 0.0:

```
df = pd.read_csv(file_path, float_precision='round_trip')

df['addCol1'] = 0.0005

df.to_csv(f"output_path", index=False, header=False)
```

Is there any way to tell pandas not to round the numbers?

Comment: Hello! Could you add your code?

Comment: This doesn't seem right. [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12877189/float64-with-pandas-to-csv) has the exact opposite problem -- it's using too many significant digits.

Comment: But the solution should be the same: use the `float_format` argument

Comment: Try open your file with txt

Comment: ahh sorry I just added the code now @JinoMichelAque

Comment: Why are you using the float_precision='round_trip'? Have you tried it with the default? Also typically a toy example or reproducible example is useful. The example code supplied does not provide something that I can try to reproduce on my end. If you could provide some of the data or toy data that produces the error you are seeing then that would be sufficient.

Comment: @TPack I was searching Stack Overflow to see if someone had a similar issue, and adding float_precision='round_trip' seemed to fix their code. But you are right, I did not need to use float_precision. float_format for to_csv worked perfectly

Comment: @pillow if it worked could you please hit the up arrow next to my comment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this line

```
df.to_csv(f"output_path", index=False, header=False)
```

to this.

```
df.to_csv(f"output_path", index=False, header=False, float_format='%.11f')
```

It'll keep float values up to 11 decimal places.