# numpy dtype float expands / appends floating values

Tags: python, numpy-ndarray

Why is the value in the float field changed?

```
>>> t=np.dtype([("",float),("",float),("",float)])
>>> v=np.array((1.1,1.12,1.123),dtype=t)
>>> v
array((1.1000000000000001, 1.1200000000000001, 1.123), 
      dtype=[('f0', '<f8'), ('f1', '<f8'), ('f2', '<f8')])
>>>
```

I am using python 2.6 
What do i need to do to preserve the value 1.1 and 1.2 ?

Comment: python 3.6 gives the correct output                                                                         >>> t=np.dtype([('',float),('',float),("",float)])                                                                       
>>> v=np.array([(1.1,1.12,1.123)],dtype=t)
>>> v
array([(1.1, 1.12, 1.123)],
      dtype=[('f0', '<f8'), ('f1', '<f8'), ('f2', '<f8')])

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python float - str - float weirdness](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1778368/python-float-str-float-weirdness)